# cordova install on ubuntu 14 doesn't seem to be working

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, npm

I'm following the instructions found here to install cordova on ubuntu:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

So far, I've run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install node
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Both commands worked fine.

Then i Ran this command to install cordova:

```
dev1@test:/$ sudo npm install -g cordova
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, elementtree@0.1.5, d8@0.4.4, init-package-json@1.4.1, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@3.8.0, npm@1.3.4)
```

And now, as per the docs, to test cordova I trying the following but nothing seems to be created:

```
dev1@test:/$ cd ~/Documents/
dev1@test:~/Documents$ mkdir dev_source
dev1@test:~/Documents$ cd dev_source/
dev1@test:~/Documents/dev_source$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
dev1@test:~/Documents/dev_source$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld -d
dev1@test:~/Documents/dev_source$ ls
dev1@test:~/Documents/dev_source$ ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x  2 dev1 dev1 4.0K Apr 17 11:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 68 dev1 dev1 4.0K Apr 17 11:18 ..
```

As you can see, there is no hello folder that is automatcially created for me. I don't get any error messages either. 
In case, I went a little further and added a platform, but that didn't work either:

dev1@test:~/Documents/dev_source$ cordova platform add android
dev1@test:~/Documents/dev_source$ cordova platform ls
dev1@test:~/Documents/dev_source$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `which cordova` say? That will tell you which (if any) binary it is hitting when you run cordova. You can continue debugging from there.

Comment: that command returns the path /usr/local/bin/cordova.  i tried to launch the app directly from that folder but nothing changed.  I also found a binary in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin

Comment: That's good - it seems to indicate that cordova installed correctly. It doesn't matter where you run it from because it is in your path. The file at `/usr/local/bin/cordova` will actually be a symbolic link to the other one you found at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't give you any more info about why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you, I found the following after digging in the README file. Executing the following seems to get `create` to work. I'm yet to try the other commands!

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
npm install -g cordova
sudo apt-get install cmake debhelper libx11-dev libicu-dev pkg-config qtbase5-dev qtchooser qtdeclarative5-dev qtfeedback5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtpim5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtsystems5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I think it's about duplicate name of `node` package that I already installed using apt-get,
then I removed it and now `cordova` works

```
sudo apt-get remove node
```